# Split values in an variable in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have a `varchar` variable been defined like this.

```
declare @IDs varchar(50)
set  @IDs ='111,123,567,'
```

Now I need to extract the last value in the list always 567.

The values in `@IDs` can be like this also

```
set  @IDs ='56,'
```

In this case we need extract only the value 56.

How can we do it?

Comment: Something similar has already been asked:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you will find this user defined function to split the string helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string splitter found here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

It is very fast, you can call it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@IDs,',')
```

This will return you a result set of all the values in the string.